# Laravel livewire print the condition @error instead of running it

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

[image: The]

Hi i have it error, i am work with laravel livewire validation but it print the conditional @error.
Helpme

```
 <div> @error('name'){{ $message }}@enderror </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@if ($errors->has('name')) <span class="text-red">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span> @endif
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Laravel updated to 5.8 solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" wire:model="name" class="form-control">
@error('name') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```

This should help.